# Passing range of numbers from terminal to Python script

Tags: python, bash, terminal, sequence

I have a python script which is executed from terminal as

`script.py 0001`

where `0001` indicates the subcase to be run. If I have to run different subcases, then I use

`script.py 0001 0002`

Question is how to specify a range as input? Lets say I want to run `0001..0008`. I got to know `seq -w 0001 0008` outputs what I desire. How to pipe this to Python as input from terminal? Or is there a different way to get this done?

Comment: argparse will help you accept CLI into your script. You can use the 'choices' arg to input a range, i.e. `... choices=range(0001,0009)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
r = sys.argv[1].split("..")
for x in range(r[0], r[1]+1):
    # ... does this do what you want ?
```

Comment: I don't know if OP has condisered 0-based indexing in python, so maybe: `range(r[0], r[1]+1)`

Comment: You are absolutely correct

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following already but did not work earlier as I did not have the subcases pulled in the script repo. The following works:

`script.py 000{1..8}`